# Extracting dynamically rendered content in a HTML page using Java

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing

I have a HTML page like

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- necessary java scripts -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Using the script, when the page renders, appropriate html content is placed withing the div element with id "content". So after the page renders there are a whole lot of html content withing div element.

Now i need to extract the dynamically rendered content within the div element using Java. Can anyone please suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to evaluate script on the page in java. You need to get some web engine to do it. You can look here: [Embedding Gecko/Webkit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653949/embeding-gecko-webkit-in-java) And try to use webkit or gecko to load page. Then you can use some java library to parse html.

Comment: I implemented using SWT and it worked fine! Thanks for the link :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse html with javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.Parser.Have a look at this link

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/bookmarks/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look through these:

http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers