# Headless browser with full javascript support for java

Tags: java, webkit, qtwebkit, headless, headless-browser

I have been using HtmlUnit (the developers did a great job) as an headless browser for some of my previous applications but the javascript support isn't working for some website that my next application will be accessing.

1. I heard about QtWebKit binding for Python but my application will be in Java or is there a Java binding for WebKit or QtWebKit?
2. Does anyone know a good headless browser for Java with full javascript support?

Comment: I'm also in a similar situation. I use HTMLUnit but the JS on some sites don't work on it. Did you find an alternative that works?

Comment: Clearly no one provided a solution as none is Java based

Comment: @John.which headless browser did you used in your java Application.

Answer (score 10):

[Nathan Ridley's answer to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/679240) is the most complete one I've found so far.

Anyway, if everything fails, you could use a Python or JS alternative, expose its funcionality as a webservice inside your server, and then your Java application could use the headless browser's funcionality through the webservice. It would be a pain to set up, but it may be a viable alternative if nothing else works as desired.

Also, [there are some "non-headless" browser wrappers for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653949/embeding-gecko-webkit-in-java); maybe it would be possible to build a testing solution around those, depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps https://github.com/machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver -- it's headless and written only in Java.

(disclosure: I'm the project owner)

Comment: I am currently using JBrowserDriver for one of my projects as well – I can totally recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/). Based on webkit it offers a complete headless browser.

Comment: Is there a Java binding for QtWebKit?

Comment: [Separate Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759421/any-java-equivalent-to-phantomjs)  
or  
[Selenium GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)

Answer (score 3):

Rhino + env.js is a full java solution, I've used it, it's not super fast but seems reasonably stable and should give you correct js support.

Answer (score 1):

Replying on an old thread, hoping it might be useful for some.

1) You can use QTJambi's QWebView. It was reasonably fast.

2) JBrowserDriver is another option.

Personally I found QT engine a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

How about a built-in webview. I'm not sure about full JS support, but a quick check on the website shows that it can support javascript.

JavaFX WebView: [JFX WebView](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/webview.html)

---

```
     private static void initWebView(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        //webView.getEngine().load("http://localhost:9009");
        webView.getEngine().loadContent("<h3 id='aa'>JAVA FX WebView, HelloWorld</h3><script>document.getElementById('aa').innerHTML='TEST'</script>");
        webView.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

---

And not related to the question, but also take a look at this: [Java-Express](https://github.com/Simonwep/java-express) or [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)

The combination may help somebody.