# What is the Java equivalent to PhantomJS?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automated-tests

I would like to know whether there is any Java library equivalent to PhantomJS. What I want to achieve is to be able to simulate form login and submit actions from a web page and also to do page scraping as well. I know jsoup does page scraping but not page automation.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Any Java equivalent? I am interested in page simulation and automation.

Answer (score 8):

There is a PhantomJS driver for Java called [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver). Maybe this suits your requirements?

Comment: I found that GhostDrive hides many capabilities of PhantomJS. Like convert page to PDF for example.

Answer (score 6):

1. Selenium with Ghostdriver/PhantomJS (This is good but there is an issue with automating file uploads for a website. Other automation activites work like a charm!)
2. Selenium with HtmlUnitDriver. HtmlUnitDriver is based on HtmlUnit which is a GUI less implementation of a browser in Java. (I have had too many exceptions with HtmlUnitDriver)
3. Jaunt - Their website is http://jaunt-api.com/. Their short description is:

   Jaunt Beta is a new, free, Java library for web-scraping & web-automation. The library provides an ultra-light headless browser (ie, no GUI). By using Jaunt your Java programs can easily perform browser-level, document-level, and DOM-level operations. Jaunt is the ideal tool when Javascript support is not required, for tasks including:
   filling out and submitting forms
   creating web-bots or web-scraping programs.
   interfacing with REST APIs or web-apps (HTML, XHTML or XML).
   automated testing.

Comment: Why not use just HtmlUnit? Jaunt is not the equivalent since it does not support JavaScript.

Comment: It's not equivalent because it has an expiration system to force you to pay when you want to use it on the long term: https://jaunt-api.com/products.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar question and answer with a list of options for you. Not all are written in Java, but there may be some suitable options for you.

[headless internet browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser/814929#814929)