# How to get hidden input value with JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have data

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="aiUlw1Yh4W47lPQearSEdTkU0rhKpziZOweq5PMTV0Q=" />
```

I am trying to select it with Jsoup.

```
 Element input = doc.select("input[name=authenticity_token]").first();

 String auth_token = input.attr("value");
```

But this not working.

I am recieving a null pointer exception at String auth_token =.

> java.lang.NullPointerException at crime.ic.Main.main(Main.java:2)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Still not working.. edited previous.

Comment: Are you sure that `doc` contains elements you want to search? Maybe they are generated by JavaScript in which case they are not part of recieved/parsed HTML.

Comment: Can you add to your post the url accessed in the code?

Comment: I have the same problem: I can see the value in IE dev panel but not in the Document retrieved. Other attributes are shown but only the `value` is not. I can see the value in web page.

Answer (score 1):

After some researching, I think I know what happens here: **the content you want to load may come from some JavaScript and is not visible/existent upon page loading.** The loading of JS happens afterwards and fills data in place, and this is not Jsoup can do. So it is beyond reach of Jsoup.

What we need is simulate/automated the loading of JS. Such tools exist.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488872/page-content-is-loaded-with-javascript-and-jsoup-doesnt-see-it/44871319#answer-39048149) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759421/any-java-equivalent-to-phantomjs) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [demo](http://try.jsoup.org/~J3NzjcCBwae2pIuVFFHK000goCA) you see that there is no problem at all with this case an the input is selected.

I believe that there may be another input with the same name that does not have a value. If that is not the case, post the issue on the JSoup github page.