# Website Scraping in Java once the whole site is loaded

Tags: java

In few websites few scripts might take some time to run which results the website **scraping** to work inefficiently or the html which is returned from the **scraper** is incomplete.How to **scrape** the website once the site scripts are fully ran.

I am using URL Connection in java when I am reading the text from it I am getting HTML which is pre matured (i.e) I have script which is a bit long which takes some time to load which changes color of the text which is not reflecting in the text which is read using URL CONNECTION.

Comment: How can I help you if I don't know what you really try to execute? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Few scripts run only after fully loading I want to  get the site scraped once the full site is loaded !

Comment: Check and wait for page to be complete loaded.

Comment: I remember using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It's a browser but headless. It will render all js on the page. You might find this thread useful [Any Java equivalent to PhantomJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759421/any-java-equivalent-to-phantomjs)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Selenium in java (and kotlin using the java libarary) to do website automation and testing
it can be set up to wait a specified time before looking for elements or wait until it is loaded, since it really just remote controls a webbrowser you can use javascript on pages and act just like any user would

https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
driver.get(url)
driver.findElement(by.name("search")).sendKeys("some query")
driver.find(by.id("submit")).click()
```

you can wait for all things to load as described here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349203/9006779
(or at least in a similar way, the api might have changed)