# headless browser supporting JS for .Net

Tags: javascript, c#, headless-browser

All I found for headless browser using C# where these packages:
[Headless browsers Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net)

In the comments often someone is angry about the kit isn't headless. Is there any alternativ which is headless being able to be used by importing an assemblie and supporting Javascript on clientside?
WatiN isn't headless, I tried this first.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634747/headless-browser-with-full-javascript-support-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this thread, looks that are other pretty good alternatives like CefSharp

[Is there an embeddable Webkit component for Windows / C# development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142184/is-there-an-embeddable-webkit-component-for-windows-c-sharp-development)