# imitate browser with java

Tags: java, ajax, browser, web-applications

I'm looking for a java-framework which enables me to easily communicate with a website.
What I'd like to do is for example:

- log into a website
- open various pages
- read information
- submit information into forms
- send ajax-requests
- read ajax-response

What I'm not looking for is a browser automation plugin like selenium. I'm trying to have my application directly communicate with the website.

That's the general outline. If you can think of a better solution for the following problem, I'm more than willing to follow your advice (:

We're working with an webapplication with an gruesome GUI. Unfortunatley we've got no means to tinker with said application or request changes to it. What I'd ike to do is to build is a client which logs into said application, fetches the data and displays them in a more appropriate manner with additional information based on that data while also providing tools to process this data and submit it back to that web-application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds offtopic but you can have a look at jsoup, it allows to interact with websites based on dom nodes. Unlike plain http clients, that's your ticket to find links & buttons and things like that.

Comment: If you want more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634747/headless-browser-with-full-javascript-support-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium does come for JAVA.  You can download it from here. http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Here is a tutorial:
https://www.airpair.com/selenium/posts/selenium-tutorial-with-java

**How Selenium web driver works**

Selenium web driver (firefox web driver) will open a web browser(firefox) for you and you can actually see what's going on. The choice of opening a browser window may not be the requirement for you. Then you can use:

- [HTMLUnitWebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver)
- PhantomJSDriverService

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Its not a framework but a library but should provide you the needed methods to interact with your web application